# CakePHP Session->valid() always returns false

Tags: php, session, cakephp

I have a CakePHP version 2.3 web application, and have run into a confusing Session issue. In the following code, $session_valid is always 'false', even though I can read the 'netid' value  just fine.

```
$this->Session->write( 'netid', $netid );

$session_valid = $this->Session->valid();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? to check if "netid" is set?

Comment: I'm just trying to determine if I have a valid session. I know that I can use $this->Session->check(), but why is $this->Session->valid() always returning false?

Answer (score -1):

I think the function you are looking for is

```
$this->Session->check('netid')
```

It checks if the session variable is set